# Excel VBA DoubleClick: Replace number with symbol

Tags: vba, excel

I have an Excel worksheet called "Overall". In there, a total of 4 numbers is listed at A13, B13, C13 and D14. The numbers are now set to be 0, 1, 3 and 4.

How do I use VBA to doubleclick one of the numbers and replace them with a symbol? If I for example click the number 0 positioned at A13, I want the number to be replaced with the symbol having the code "24EA". That symbol is a 0 with a circle around it. I then want it to be possible to click the number and then turn it in to a normal 0 without a circle.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean) 

If Intersect(Target, Range("A13:D13")) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub 

If Target.Value = "0" Then 
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = ChrW(&H24EA) 
    With Selection.Font 
       .Name = "Calibri" 
       .Size = 16 
    End With
ElseIf ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = ChrW(&H24EA) Then 
    Target = "0" 
    With Selection.Font 
        .Name = "Calibri" 
        .Size = 9 
    End With
End If
```

Is it even possible - and if so how can it be made?

Comment: Have you tried anything? I'm sure there are a lot of examples out there if you search for the double click event.

Comment: I have tried this, but when I click A13 on the number 0 I get this error: "Compile error: Else without If".

`Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
If Intersect(Target, Range("A13:D13")) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

  If Target.Value = "0" Then
        ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = ChrW(&H24EA)
         With Selection.Font
        .Name = "Calibri"
        .Size = 16
        
    ElseIf ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = ChrW(&H24EA) Then
        Target = "0"
        With Selection.Font
        .Name = "Calibri"
        .Size = 9
       
    End If`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add something similar to this into the VBA-module of your Worksheet

```
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
    With ActiveCell
        Select Case .Value
            Case "0": .Value = ChrW("&H24EA")
            Case ChrW("&H24EA"): .Value = 0 ' untested
            ' ...
        End Select
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Seems like it is working! However, when I click the 0 again (the symbol with the circle) it will not turn back to the number zero?

Comment: You don't have to convert it. You could use `ChrW("&H24EA")`

Comment: Thank you `Tim Edwards`, I didn't know that and updated the answer accordingly.
`M.V.`: just try changing it back, even if there might be a more sophisticated way to do that

Comment: Martin Dreher thank you very much! Problem is solved.

`Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
    With ActiveCell
        Select Case .Value
            Case "0": .Value = ChrW(9450)
            Case ChrW(9450): .Value = 0
            Case "1": .Value = ChrW(9312)
            Case ChrW(9312): .Value = 1
            Case "2": .Value = ChrW(9313)
            Case ChrW(9313): .Value = 2
            Case "3": .Value = ChrW(9314)
            Case ChrW(9314): .Value = 3
        End Select
    End With
End Sub`